# How to fix repeating images in table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

im using PFQueryTableViewController from Parse and i noticed when scrolling that images are being repeated. how can i prevent this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Item";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    PFObject *photoObject = [object objectForKey:@"toObject"];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:photoObject.objectId block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error) {
        // Do something with the returned PFObject in the gameScore variable.

        PFImageView *photo = (PFImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        photo.file = [gameScore objectForKey:@"image"];
        [photo loadInBackground:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        }];

    }];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: By showing your code, it probably is not a general bug in the framework but in the code you wrote - would you care to share the relevant part please?

Comment: added cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @luk2302 i was thinking maybe its because im querying it in cellForRow?

Comment: an unguarded query in cellForRowAtIndexPath is always wrong.

Comment: what do you mean @danh

Comment: That method runs each time a cell is scrolled into view, so, several times per second you're launching a query, including repeats of the same query, over and over.

Comment: yeah im thinking of querying it at viewdidload and putting it into an array and then showing it at cellforrow

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns the image asynchronously and places it in the cell object captured in your completion block.   There is no guaranty that, when the query returns, you cell object hasn't already been reused by the tableview for another row.

Also, updating UI components in a background thread (which I suspect the completion block will be) is also a source of UI problems.

One way around this could be to capture the index path (instead of the cell) and use tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath() in the completion block to make sure you're updating the right cell with the image.   You should also dispatch this to the main thread in order to avoid conflicting with other updates (such as having the cell you're trying to update be victim to yet another reuse - less probable but not impossible)